# PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone must be called from Looper thread

Tags: android, voicemail

I call `PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone()` in the `callVoicemail()` function in TwelveKeyDialer.java, then I get this log message as the title describes, and the twelveKeyDialer app crashes, how does this happen?  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are Calling the PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone() from a thread other than Main thread. You need to call this from a thread which has called Looper.prepare().

Easiest way is to call this from UI thread. Use [RunonUithread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: I have tried "RunonUithread",but got other problems ,maybe there are mistakes in the other place of my code,now i try another way without calling PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone() and i works~  thanks all the same~

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone(getApplicationContext())` before `PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone()`?

In my experience you can call it in in the Activity create method.

You will need to add `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission and sign the application with the system keys if you need to make changes to the phone.You will need to use the android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" the manifest tag.

Shlomo Kut